# Fixed-size memory allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17, memory-optimization, boost

I've been trying to implement a simple Boost PMR allocator that has a fixed amount of memory. My first implementation (which can be found [here](https://github.com/irods/irods/blob/12ce61bc6ba5b30091f174c894b8807811da45ef/lib/core/include/fixed_buffer_resource.hpp)) had undefined behavior and did not handle memory alignment.

I've been doing a lot of reading around these topics and while I'm still unclear about some of it, I believe the code posted below is closer to a real solution.

It would be very helpful if someone could review the code below for the following:

- undefined behavior
- proper handling of memory alignment
- obvious performance enhancements

Also, is it possible to calculate how many bytes are needed to align a buffer? See **TODO** comment in `allocate_block()`. What I have there now is the following, but it feels wrong.

```cpp
const auto max_space_needed = sizeof(header) + sizeof(void*) + _bytes + _alignment;
```

For the most part, the implementation appears to work, but I want to make sure I've covered as many things as possible since this will be included in the next release of the software I work on.

```cpp
#ifndef IRODS_FIXED_BUFFER_RESOURCE_HPP
#define IRODS_FIXED_BUFFER_RESOURCE_HPP

/// \file

#include <boost/container/pmr/memory_resource.hpp>

#include <fmt/format.h>

#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

/// A namespace containing components meant to be used with Boost.Container's PMR library.
namespace irods::experimental::pmr
{
    /// A \p fixed_buffer_resource is a special purpose memory resource class template that
    /// allocates memory from the buffer given on construction. It allows applications to
    /// enforce a cap on the amount of memory available to components.
    ///
    /// This class implements a first-fit scheme and is NOT thread-safe.
    ///
    /// \tparam ByteRep The memory representation for the underlying buffer. Must be \p char
    ///                 or \p std::byte.
    ///
    /// \since 4.2.11
    template <typename ByteRep>
    class fixed_buffer_resource
        : public boost::container::pmr::memory_resource
    {
    public:
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<ByteRep, char> ||
                      std::is_same_v<ByteRep, unsigned char> ||
                      std::is_same_v<ByteRep, std::uint8_t> ||
                      std::is_same_v<ByteRep, std::byte>);

        /// Constructs a \p fixed_buffer_resource using the given buffer as the allocation
        /// source.
        ///
        /// \param[in] _buffer      The buffer that will be used for allocations.
        /// \param[in] _buffer_size The size of the buffer in bytes.
        ///
        /// \throws std::invalid_argument If any of the incoming constructor arguments do not
        ///                               satisfy construction requirements.
        ///
        /// \since 4.2.11
        fixed_buffer_resource(ByteRep* _buffer, std::int64_t _buffer_size)
            : boost::container::pmr::memory_resource{}
            , buffer_{_buffer}
            , buffer_size_(_buffer_size)
            , allocated_{}
            , headers_{}
        {
            if (!_buffer || _buffer_size <= 0) {
                const auto* msg_fmt = "fixed_buffer_resource: invalid constructor arguments "
                                      "[buffer={}, size={}].";
                const auto msg = fmt::format(msg_fmt, fmt::ptr(_buffer), _buffer_size);
                throw std::invalid_argument{msg_fmt};
            }

            std::size_t space_left = buffer_size_;

            // Make sure the buffer is aligned for the header type.
            if (!std::align(alignof(header), sizeof(header), buffer_, space_left)) {
                throw std::runtime_error{"fixed_buffer_resource: internal memory alignment error. "};
            }

            headers_ = new (buffer_) header;
            headers_->size = space_left - sizeof(header);
            headers_->prev = nullptr;
            headers_->next = nullptr;
            headers_->used = false;
        } // fixed_buffer_resource

        fixed_buffer_resource(const fixed_buffer_resource&) = delete;
        auto operator=(const fixed_buffer_resource&) -> fixed_buffer_resource& = delete;

        ~fixed_buffer_resource() = default;

        /// Returns the number of bytes used by the client.
        ///
        /// The value returned does not include memory used for tracking allocations.
        ///
        /// \return An unsigned integral type.
        ///
        /// \since 4.2.11
        auto allocated() const noexcept -> std::size_t
        {
            return allocated_;
        } // allocated

        /// Returns the number of bytes used for tracking allocations.
        ///
        /// \return An unsigned integral type.
        ///
        /// \since 4.2.11
        auto allocation_overhead() const noexcept -> std::size_t
        {
            return 0;
        } // allocation_overhead

        /// Writes the state of the allocation table to the output stream.
        ///
        /// \since 4.2.11
        auto print(std::ostream& _os) const -> void
        {
            std::size_t i = 0;

            for (auto* h = headers_; h; h = h->next) {
                _os << fmt::format("{:>3}. Header Info [{}]: {{previous={:14}, next={:14}, used={:>5}, data={:14}, data_size={}}}\n",
                                   i,
                                   fmt::ptr(h),
                                   fmt::ptr(h->prev),
                                   fmt::ptr(h->next),
                                   h->used,
                                   fmt::ptr(address_of_data_segment(h)),
                                   h->size);
                ++i;
            }
        } // print

    protected:
        auto do_allocate(std::size_t _bytes, std::size_t _alignment) -> void* override
        {
            for (auto* h = headers_; h; h = h->next) {
                if (auto* p = allocate_block(_bytes, _alignment, h); p) {
                    return p;
                }
            }

            throw std::bad_alloc{};
        } // do_allocate

        auto do_deallocate(void* _p, std::size_t _bytes, std::size_t _alignment) -> void override
        {
            void* data = *(static_cast<void**>(_p) - 1);
            auto* h = reinterpret_cast<header*>(static_cast<ByteRep*>(data) - sizeof(header));

            assert(h != nullptr);
            assert(h->size == _bytes);

            h->used = false;

            coalesce_with_next_unused_block(h);
            coalesce_with_next_unused_block(h->prev);

            allocated_ -= _bytes;
        } // do_deallocate

        auto do_is_equal(const boost::container::pmr::memory_resource& _other) const noexcept -> bool override
        {
            return this == &_other;
        } // do_is_equal

    private:
        // Header associated with an allocation within the underlying memory buffer.
        // All data segments will be preceded by a header.
        //
        // Memory Layout:
        //
        //     +------------------------------------------------------------------+
        //     | padding | header |                 data segment                  |
        //     +------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
        //                        | padding | unaligned pointer | aligned pointer |
        //                        +-----------------------------------------------+
        //
        struct header
        {
            std::size_t size;   // Size of the memory block (excluding all management info).
            header* prev;       // Pointer to the previous header block.
            header* next;       // Pointer to the next header block.
            bool used;          // Indicates whether the memory is in use.
        }; // struct header

        auto address_of_data_segment(header* _h) const noexcept -> ByteRep*
        {
            return reinterpret_cast<ByteRep*>(_h) + sizeof(header);
        } // address_of_data_segment

        auto aligned_alloc(std::size_t _bytes, std::size_t _alignment, header* _h)
            -> std::tuple<void*, std::size_t>
        {
            // The unused memory is located right after the header.
            void* data = address_of_data_segment(_h);
            auto space_left = _h->size - sizeof(void*);

            // Reserve space for the potentially unaligned pointer.
            void* aligned_data = static_cast<ByteRep*>(data) + sizeof(void*);

            if (!std::align(_alignment, _bytes, aligned_data, space_left)) {
                return {nullptr, 0};
            }

            // Store the address of the original allocation directly before the
            // aligned memory.
            new (static_cast<ByteRep*>(aligned_data) - sizeof(void*)) void*{data};

            return {aligned_data, space_left};
        } // aligned_alloc

        auto allocate_block(std::size_t _bytes, std::size_t _alignment, header* _h) -> void*
        {
            if (_h->used) {
                return nullptr;
            }

            // Return the block if it matches the requested number of bytes.
            if (_bytes == _h->size) {
                if (auto* aligned_data = std::get<void*>(aligned_alloc(_bytes, _alignment, _h)); aligned_data) {
                    _h->used = true;
                    allocated_ += _bytes;
                    return aligned_data;
                }
            }

            // TODO Is it possible to compute the amount of memory needed to satisfy
            // the allocation and alignment requirements? I'm not sure if this line
            // is correct.
            const auto max_space_needed = sizeof(header) + sizeof(void*) + _bytes + _alignment;

            // Split the data segment managed by this header if it is large enough
            // to satisfy the allocation request and management information.
            if (max_space_needed < _h->size) {
                auto [aligned_data, space_left] = aligned_alloc(_bytes, _alignment, _h);

                if (!aligned_data) {
                    return nullptr;
                }

                void* aligned_header_storage = static_cast<ByteRep*>(aligned_data) + _bytes;

                if (!std::align(alignof(header), sizeof(header), aligned_header_storage, space_left)) {
                    return nullptr;
                }

                // Construct a new header after the memory managed by "_h".
                // The new header manages unused memory.
                auto* new_header = new (aligned_header_storage) header;
                new_header->size = space_left - _bytes - sizeof(header);
                new_header->prev = _h;
                new_header->next = _h->next;
                new_header->used = false;

                // Update the allocation table links for the header just after the
                // newly added header.
                if (auto* next_header = _h->next; next_header) {
                    next_header->prev = new_header;
                }

                // Adjust the current header's size and mark it as used.
                _h->size = _bytes;
                _h->next = new_header;
                _h->used = true;

                allocated_ += _bytes;

                return aligned_data;
            }

            return nullptr;
        } // allocate_block

        auto coalesce_with_next_unused_block(header* _h) -> void
        {
            if (!_h || _h->used) {
                return;
            }

            auto* header_to_remove = _h->next;

            // Coalesce the memory blocks if they are not in use by the client.
            // This means that "_h" will absorb the header at "_h->next".
            if (header_to_remove && !header_to_remove->used) {
                // TODO This does not consider the header's size.
                // How should I handle this?
                _h->size += header_to_remove->size;
                _h->next = header_to_remove->next;

                // Make sure the links between the headers are updated appropriately.
                // (i.e. "_h" and "header_to_remove->next" need their links updated).
                if (auto* new_next_header = header_to_remove->next; new_next_header) {
                    new_next_header->prev = _h;
                }
            }
        } // coalesce_with_next_unused_block

        void* buffer_;
        std::size_t buffer_size_;
        std::size_t allocated_;
        header* headers_;
    }; // fixed_buffer_resource
} // namespace irods::experimental::pmr

#endif // IRODS_FIXED_BUFFER_RESOURCE_HPP
```

Comment: You're using Boost.PMR instead of std::pmr, with C++17?

Comment: Yes. The project I work on is tied to Clang 6.0.1 and Boost 1.67.

Comment: But pmr is available for the std collections in C++17; just because Boost is also in use doesn't mean you have to use Boost.Container.

Comment: Right. However, I don't think the version of Clang we use has support for std::pmr. I believe I checked for that before, but I'll check again.

Comment: Yeah, Clang 6 does not appear to have support for pmr. It has some headers, but the implementation is not complete. Also, I forgot to mention we are using libc++.

Comment: Right; it's not in libc++ (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17).  I assume you're using that option since this is a library feature not a language feature.  You can also use gcc's libstdc++

Comment: BTW, when I've implemented a simple memory pool with variable sized allocations, I worked off the algorithm from Knuth's TAOP.

Answer (score 2):

Use inline initializers on your members rather than constants in the only constructor.  You can write the members as:

```
    void* buffer_ = nullptr;
    std::size_t buffer_size_;
    std::size_t allocated_ = 0;
    header* headers_ = nullptr;
```

And then your constructor needs only:

```
 : buffer_size_(_buffer_size)
```

I notice that the parameter is `uint64_t` while the member uses `size_t`.

Comment: The parameter type and member type are different on purpose. This is for situations where a negative value is passed to the constructor. We want to be able to detect those cases.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     static_assert(std::is_same_v<ByteRep, char> ||
>                   std::is_same_v<ByteRep, unsigned char> ||
>                   std::is_same_v<ByteRep, std::uint8_t> ||
>                   std::is_same_v<ByteRep, std::byte>);
> ```

Why those four particular types, but not `signed char`?  Perhaps what we really care about is

```
   static_assert(sizeof (ByteRep) == 1);
```

---

> ```
>             const auto* msg_fmt = "fixed_buffer_resource: invalid constructor arguments "
>                                   "[buffer={}, size={}].";
>             const auto msg = fmt::format(msg_fmt, fmt::ptr(_buffer), _buffer_size);
>             throw std::invalid_argument{msg_fmt};
> ```

Why do we discard `msg`, and populate the exception using the *format string*?

---

The handling of alignment is quite tricky.  I don't see any obvious issues.  The non-obvious issues need to be exercised using a good test suite; it's a shame you didn't include your tests in the review request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The msg/msg_fmt is a typo due to experimenting with online editors (godbolt, etc). I have a very basic unit test which can be found [here](https://github.com/irods/irods/blob/master/unit_tests/src/test_fixed_buffer_resource.cpp). What things should I test for other than allocation/deallocation? Is `signed char` different from `char`? Wouldn't it be possible for someone to pass an empty class as `ByteRep` if I only checked for a size of 1?

Comment: re `signed char` etc.:  For casting to/from raw memory, the language only treats (plain) `char` , `unsigned char`, and `std::byte` as special.  However, I think he avoids UB by using placement `new` for the header instead of just pointing into the buffer and calling it a header, even though it has no constructor or destructor.

Comment: @JDługosz, I guess that means that `std::uint8_t` should be removed from the list of acceptable types, then, rather than adding `signed char`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in `allocate_block()`.

```cpp
                auto [aligned_data, space_left] = aligned_alloc(_bytes, _alignment, _h);

                if (!aligned_data) {
                    return nullptr;
                }

                void* aligned_header_storage = static_cast<ByteRep*>(aligned_data) + _bytes;

                if (!std::align(alignof(header), sizeof(header), aligned_header_storage, space_left)) {
                    return nullptr;
                }

                // Construct a new header after the memory managed by "_h".
                // The new header manages unused memory.
                auto* new_header = new (aligned_header_storage) header;
```

- `space_left` is not updated to reflect the allocation of `_bytes` bytes. This means the call to `std::align()` for `aligned_header_storage` is incorrect.
- `space_left` needs to be checked to make sure there is enough space left in the buffer to hold an additional `header`.